# Tensorflow model performs poorly on new data, don't know where to look at

Tags: tensorflow

I have a model that I trained over a training set. I use a simple 3 layer Dense model with 11 inputs (floats) and 3 outputs (floats). The input are normalised using `tf.keras.utils.normalize`. I am working with a regression problem.

I use a small subset of the training set also as testing set (using the validation_split). The model was adequate during training (RMSE of 70 and accuracy of 84%). When I evaluated the model on new data (but similar to the training data), the model performed really bad: first the loss error RMSE was 60 (lower than the one during training) and second the accuracy was dropped to 14%.

I know I am not very specific with my description, but I am looking for possible pointers to where to look at when there is such a huge difference in performance from training to real-data.

Here is roughly how I set up the model:

```
    x_train, y_train= self.get_training_data()
    x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation=tf.nn.relu),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation=tf.nn.relu),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation=tf.nn.relu),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=self._root_mean_squared_error, metrics=['accuracy'])

    es_callback = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3)

    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_split = 0.3, epochs=100, batch_size=50, shuffle=True, callbacks=[es_callback])
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if you are working on classification, but you may want to check if your classes order are not changed when testing on your new dataset. 14% is way less than full random (3 classes = 33% acc), so it seems your network is doing a good job at predicting the wrong classes, which shows he is probably classifying class (1, 2, 3) as class (2, 3, 1).

Comment: I am sorry, it's a good point. I am working on regression.

Comment: Then what exactly is your accuracy function for regression ? As stated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142873/how-to-determine-the-accuracy-of-regression-which-measure-should-be-used), accuracy is  not a percentage but often a metric such as MSE in regression tasks.

Comment: I am using RMSE for the loss function and then with tensorflow I am using the 'accuracy' metric which reports a value from 0..1 I think.

Comment: I have just posted the code I am using, if that could help to identify what's the problem. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: I'd rather use MSE/RMSE for metrics as well, the accuracy metric is appropriate for classification problems, not regression ones, this is why it gives weird values here. Maybe you can have a look [here](https://keras.io/api/metrics/regression_metrics) at what Keras recommends using.

Comment: I see, I have now changed them and indeed the error is not different anymore. I now use MSE as the loss function and RMSE as an extra metric. I will try to use it again and see what happens. Thanks for your time.